# Rename a column within a HDF5 file

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables, h5py

I am looking to rename a column within one of my HDF5 file to something else but I cannot fathom how to do it.

```
>>> h5 = h5py.File(hdf5file, 'r')
>>> h5['/ook'].dtype
dtype([('fubar', '<f4'), ... )]
```

I want to rename `'fubar'` to something else. Clearly, I want to rename *all* the first elements of the `dtype`, not just the first one.

Using h5dump, the data I want to rename is described as this:

```
  DATASET "log" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
         H5T_IEEE_F32LE "fubar";
         ...
```

Finally, I did try this:

```
>>> h5['/log'].dtype.names = ('0', ...)
```

But, again no luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is not possible because it is expressly forbidden in the specification.